# Animating to View Controller that is a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to use transitioningDelegate to apply custom animations when transitioning from VC1 to VC2.  This, in general, works but now a need a navigation bar in VC2. So, I embedded VC2 in a navigation controller which gets me my navigation bar but now the methods for doing the animation (via transitioningDelegate) are not called. I can't use the animation for navigation controllers because VC2 is essentially the root of my navigation controller so, subsequent push/pop can be animated but not the first one.

Is there anything special needed when animating to navigation controller?

This is in Xcode 7, iOS 9 and using Storyboards.

Please help.

PS: Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, to your question, it seems like in your animation code, you should use the navigation controller object instead of `VC2` to be part of the animation, not `VC2`, because you embed it, otherwise, you won't have your `VC2` in a navigation stack.

From my experience, transitioningDelegate is about presenting a view controller with custom modal presentation type. It has limitations if you want advanced view controllers transitions, because not every scenario is suitable for 'presenting(modal)' a controller, such as I got a login view controller, and presenting your home view controller on a login controller is kind of limited.

I used to create a container controller, which is the parent of all the others controllers, so I can use

```
- (void)transitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController 
                    toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController 
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                             options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options 
                          animations:(void (^)(void))animations 
                          completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

to gain the ultimate control of the transit and animations among child view controllers. It has nothing to do with modal, navigation controller, they just have to be in a common parent view controller, like `appDelegate.window.rootViewController`

Let's say we have a parent controller named `parentViewController`

We manually add `VC1` and `navigationController`(which embeds `VC2`) into `parentViewController` and transit them with animations you like:

```
[parentViewController addChildViewController:VC1]; 
[parentViewController addChildViewController:navigationController]; 
[VC1 willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

[parentViewController transitionFromViewController:VC1
                                  toViewController:navigationController
                                          duration:duration
                                           options:options
                                        animations:^{
                                          // your animation code, or do nothing and use UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve as options to have a default animation
                                      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          [navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];
                                          [VC1 removeFromParentViewController];
                                      }];
```

note

```
[VC1 willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];
[VC1 removeFromParentViewController];
```

They are essential to be called.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct. My issue was that I indeed need to use the transitioning delegate in the navigation controller (as you pointed out in your first paragraph).

Comment: sure. you definitely will want the most flexible way to control someday :)